# hightlight multiple selected item(s)

Tags: android, listview

i am populating my list view with cursor adapter, and i want to allow user to long press on any item(s) and perform available actions using action mode. i am using support library as my **minimum sdk version =10**

Problem: when i long click on the item action mode is displayed but the item is not highlighted as selected.

here is my activity_layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the layout for list row :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/activated_background"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_id"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_amount"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

i have used `android:background="@drawable/activated_background"` for row layout and it is defined in drawable folder as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_activated_holo" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

when i long click on the item, it doesn't get highlighted.

here is my activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ActionMode _actionMode =null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    SQLiteDatabase db =  new ItemDbContract(getBaseContext()).getReadableDatabase();
    String selection[] = {ProductTable._ID,ProductTable.TITLE,ProductTable.Price};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(ProductTable.TABLE_NAME, selection, null, null, null, null, null);

    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setAdapter(new ItemsListAdapter(getBaseContext(), cursor));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(_actionMode!=null)
                {
                    listView.setItemChecked(arg2, true);
                    System.out.println("item position checked="+arg2);
                }
        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("long clicked on "+arg2);
            listView.setItemChecked(arg2, true);
            ((ActionBarActivity)MainActivity.this).startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallback);
            return true;
        }
    });

}


ActionMode.Callback actionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        _actionMode = arg0;
        _actionMode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.item_journal_context_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode arg0, MenuItem arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
};
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solved my problem by maintaining a list of selected item in custom adapter and setting   different background for the selected item.